# Does the psionic power sustenance cover a vampire's need for blood?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Can a vampire who is able to manifest the *sustenance* power use that power to satisfy their thirst for blood?

Comment: What sourcebooks are you using? Just Dreamscarred Press' Psionics Unleased?

Answer (score 7):

#### Regular Pathfinder vampires, I would probably rule yes

Pathfinder vampires just need “blood.” Their physical needs don’t seem to be very picky about it—they derive pleasure from drinking blood from intelligent creatures, apparently, but they don’t suffer withdrawal or other problems from drinking animal blood.

*Sustenance*, meanwhile, is worded pretty broadly: it says it covers your nourishment, full-stop. You neither feel hunger nor suffer from starvation when you use it. If an obligate carnivore (read: creature that absolutely must eat meet to survive, like most cats—see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivore#Obligate_carnivores)) manifests *sustenance*, it is nourished by that. Why should it be any different for an obligate sanguivore?

#### Corruption vampires, no

The [optional corruption rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/corruption/vampirism/) go into more details, and there the vampire is required to deal Constitution damage to satisfy their thirst. Since *sustenance* does not deal Constitution damage to anyone, it wouldn’t satisfy.

#### *Lords of the Night* vampires, no

Dreamscarred Press has another product, *Lords of the Night*, which basically redoes vampires in a lot more detail, intended for campaigns where the players themselves are vampires and are really digging into life as vampires. The hunger of those vampires explicitly specifies that they must gain temporary hit points from their bite—nothing else counts. *Sustenance* isn’t their bite. So they wouldn’t.

#### Dreamscarred Press response

I asked Dreamscarred Press about this question. In addition to pointing out *Lords of the Night* and that those vampires’ thirst works differently, there was some discussion on the question with respect to Pathfinder vampires. Andreas Rönnqvist (co-founder/owner of Dreamscarred Press and co-author of *Ultimate Psionics*) concluded

> I think I would be ok with a psionic vampire living off of psionic energy instead
>
> But OUR vampires still need to fang people

Comment: Note, [vampires who transformed through corruption](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/corruption/vampirism/), also wouldn't work. They must deal constitution damage through their bite.

Answer (score 2):

### It's unclear, but probably not.

The text of the [Sustenance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/s/sustenance/) power is fairly succinct.

> You can go without food and water for one day. Each time you manifest this power, your body manufactures sufficient solid and liquid nourishment to satisfy your needs for that time.

The power specifically calls out 'food and water' which does not cover your Vampire needs. The second half seems to be more fluff than actual use, but does indicate that 'manufactures... liquid nourishment'. This is obviously referring to the *water* intake, but a particularly lenient GM might allow you to make a liquid of your choice.

That being said... your body is now making blood. It was before... is this new magical blood good enough to cover your unholy desires? I believe most GM's are going to go with 'no, a 2nd level power cannot sate your need for the blood of the living. It's not a matter of sustenance, but something deeper and darker'.

Comment: Vampires can subsist on animal blood and the like, though, making Pathfinder’s vampires much more capable of avoiding murder than vampires from some of the fictional settings I could name. That makes it a little more believable that a 2nd-level power could handle this.

Comment: A fair point, but I still think it was outside of the intended scope